# Cannot get ID data to display using Flat UI select box

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Flat UI http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/ as an Twitter Bootstrap extension to my site.

I'd like to be able to use the "select" box styling that they provide, which is:

```
<select name="huge" class="select-block mbl" id="fui-select">
  <option value="0">My Profile</option>
  <option value="1">My Friends</option>
</select
```

But I want to pass in a id value and which is created from a db, I dont want to use a pre fixed list as per the example.

I thought I could just do the following (adding **myiddata** to the select line)

```
<select name="huge" class="select-block mbl" id=" **myiddata** fui-select">

</select
```

But this is not returning the results. I cannot find an answer to this in the documentation provided.

Is the approach correct? or is there another way that I have to pass data into a select box?

Comment: Just want to comment on your `id` attribute, you can't have multiple id's on the same element.

Comment: O I see so would I put it a level down, between the select tags?

Comment: @JohnKlakegg Is right, you can't have multiple id's (more specifically _spaces_ in the `id=""` attribute. Remove the "fui-select" id and replace it with your desired id.

The JavaScript should be generating the dropdown component from the class ('select-block') and not the `id` attribute, so everything should work fine.

Comment: @zesda thanks, if you'd like to make it the answer i will accept it. CHeers

Comment: Thanks, that's very kind of you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JohnKlakegg Is right, you can't have multiple id's (more specifically spaces in the id="" attribute. Remove the "fui-select" id and replace it with your desired id.

The JavaScript should be generating the dropdown component from the class ('select-block') and not the id attribute, so everything should work fine.

I hope this helps :)